# How to release memory after NSDocument window has closed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I am working on a multi-window and document-based app. NSDocument handles the windows. Each document is about 80-100 MB in size.

When a window is closed, its memory footprint doesn't disappear at all. It seems that *nothing* is released whenever a window closes. Every delegate I've set should be `self`. Memory usage is pretty stable otherwise, but something is kept alive.

What could be causing this? Any hints where I could start debugging the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My NSDocument implementation had a `@property (nonatomic) NSWindow *thisWindow`. The nonatomic property kept the whole window alive, even when set to `nil`.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it works now. Then your question does not seem to have no viable answer when it appears in a list.